# How can I make an ajax call from inside my function?

Tags: jquery

I have a popup window that is riggered by a hover function that works fine on it’t own and an ajax call that works fine on its own. Now my goal is to make an ajaxcall from  inside the hover function and return a partal view in a div tag.  I’ve seen many samples but haven’t been able to make them work so.  Here’s what I have.  Can someone please help me with this one or point me toward a solution that’s similar to mine?

Here’s the code that I’m trying:

```
$(function () {

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm.dd.yy' })
    $("#dropdownselected1").val($("#categories").val());

});

$(function () {

    var moveLeft = 0;
    var moveDown = 0;

    $('a.popper').hover(function (e) {
        var id = {a:171};
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/Attendance/Details",
            data:id,
            datatype:"html",
            sucess:function(data){
                $('#div_id').html(data);
            }
        });

        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        $(target).show();

        moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
        moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);

    }, function () {
        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        $(target).hide();
    });

    $('a.popper').mousemove(function (e) {
        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
        maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
        windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
        windowRight = 0;
        maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);
        if (maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight) {
            leftD = maxLeft;
        }

        topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
        maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
        windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
        maxTop = topD;
        windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());

        if (maxBottom > windowBottom) {
            topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
        } else if (maxTop < windowTop) {
            topD = windowTop + 20;
        }

        $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);

    });
});
```

EDIT
I updated success... still doesn't call the action.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you made a demo on something like jsbin.com and include only relevant code (minimal). http://sscce.org/

Comment: Do you have the `sucess:` typo in the original code, or was it just a copying error?

Comment: @m59 Great resource, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to think of problems like this in terms of separation of responsibilities.

You have a piece of code that represents your data, a Model. Then you have a View that you have to update, and you have a Controller that handles interaction or input from the user and does something with it.

First wrapping your 'model' in this case with a function so you can abstract away any knowledge about the server from your UI. It just knows it has to get data.

Instead of using the `success` handler, checkout the [.promise() API](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). jQuery.ajax returns promises so we can use them to our advantage.

```
function getData(id) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax.aspx',
    data: id
  });
}
```

Calling `getData(id)` returns a Promise, which is just something that happens in the future. It's a promise that no matter what, you're always going to get a value of some sort back.

In this case though, we're going to swap out ajax for an offline example using [$.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

```
function getData(data) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  // Imagine this timeout was actually the handler for XMLHttpRequest
  setTimeout(function() {
    // This is what $.ajax does internally.
    // it just `resolves` the promise it handed you.
    dfd.resolve("it works! " + data);

    // We could also reject it if something went wrong.
    // dfd.reject("omg error");
  }, 1000);
  // $.Deferred makes promises just like $.ajax!
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

We can reduce our event handler, or Controller, down to one function, by inspecting the `type` member of the event object. This allows us to write cleaner code and cut down on requery (using  the form `$('#someting')` repeatedly).

```
function onHover(ev) {
  var el = $(this);
  var target = $('#' + el.data('popbox'));

  if (ev.type === 'mouseenter') {
    // Do code to setup API call
    target.text('loading').show();

    // Do API call
    getData('33')  //= returns a promise

    // Then, do code to handle API call
    .then(function(data) {
      target.html(data);
    })

    // If it fails, do something else
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  // mouseout
  else {
    target.hide().empty();
  }
}
```

Lastly, to have our "controller" listen to the DOM, we use `.on()` instead of deprecated `.hover()` syntax, which is just sugar for the mouseenter and mouseout events.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseout', 'a.hover', onHover);
```

As an aside; pure jQuery makes it kind of tough to write a true controller, because in this case it knows way too much about the DOM and is very coupled to it's structure. You could abstract this further with the likes of `$.proxy`.

Instead of attaching to a specific set of element(s) `<a.hover>`, we're binding this function to the `<body>`, and listening for events to bubble up, filtered by selector `a.hover`. This is much more performant when dealing with many `<a.hover>` elements.

See [here](http://jsbin.com/UBIluXAs/2/edit) for a working example. Hope that helps!